# Error installing stylish-haskell on Mac OS X on Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-platform

I get the same error relatively consistently when trying to install the stylish-haskell package off of hackage.
The install went swimmingly until it got to installing conduit, which doesn't come anywhere near installing correctly.

The ending of the error message:

```
        17 warnings and 2 errors generated.
        Failed to install conduit-1.0.8
        cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
        conduit-1.0.8 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
        ExitFailure 1
        stylish-haskell-0.5.8.0 depends on conduit-1.0.8 which failed to install. 
        yaml-0.8.5.1 depends on conduit-1.0.8 which failed to install.
```

The full terminal output I get is:

```
        Configuring conduit-1.0.8...

        /var/folders/cn/67wph78d62qc1v_lm7z2mb980000gn/T/32054.c:1:12:
             warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
        int foo() {}
                   ^
        1 warning generated.
        Building conduit-1.0.8...
        Preprocessing library conduit-1.0.8...

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:165:14:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    let c' = c - S.length bs
                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:166:18:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    assert (c' >= 0) $
                             ^

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:171:34:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                                pullLimited c'
                                             ^

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:281:62:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    await >>= maybe (return $ L.fromChunks $ front []) go'
                                                                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:283:11:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    go' bs =
                      ^

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:299:39:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    await >>= maybe (return ()) go'
                                                  ^

        Data/Conduit/Binary.hs:301:11:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    go' bs =
                      ^
        7 warnings generated.

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:79:47:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        -- * /i/ is the type of values for this @Pipe@'s input stream.
                                                      ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:81:47:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        -- * /o/ is the type of values for this @Pipe@'s output stream.
                                                      ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:152:64:
             warning: \u used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
                local f (NeedInput p c) = NeedInput (\i -> local f (p i)) (\u -> local f (c u))
                                                                           ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:170:62:
             warning: \u used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
                listen (NeedInput p c) = NeedInput (\i -> listen (p i)) (\u -> listen (c u))
                                                                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:175:26:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                     return $ do (x,w') <- listen p
                                     ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:176:46:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                                 return (x, w `mappend` w')
                                                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:180:58:
             warning: \u used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
                pass (NeedInput p c) = NeedInput (\i -> pass (p i)) (\u -> pass (c u))
                                                                     ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:197:74:
             warning: \u used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
                catchError (NeedInput p c) f = NeedInput (\i -> catchError (p i) f) (\u -> catchError (c u) f)
                                                                                     ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:306:50:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        awaitForever :: Monad m => (i -> Pipe l i o r m r') -> Pipe l i o r m r
                                                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:338:4:
             error: invalid preprocessing directive
              #-}
               ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:543:13:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    pipe' <- mpipe
                        ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:544:18:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    case pipe' of
                             ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:546:29:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                        _ -> return pipe'
                                        ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:581:83:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        mapInput f f' (NeedInput p c)    = NeedInput (mapInput f f' . p . f) (mapInput f f' . c)
                                                                                          ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:584:82:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        mapInput f f' (Leftover p i)     = maybe id (flip Leftover) (f' i) $ mapInput f f' p
                                                                                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:605:4:
             error: invalid preprocessing directive
              #-}
               ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:650:35:
             warning: \u used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
                    loop = awaitE >>= either (\u -> return (u, r)) (\_ -> loop)
                                              ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:671:14:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                let final' = do
                         ^

        Data/Conduit/Internal.hs:674:58:
             warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                return (liftIO (I.writeIORef ref False) >> src, final')
                                                                     ^
        17 warnings and 2 errors generated.
        Failed to install conduit-1.0.8
        cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
        conduit-1.0.8 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
        ExitFailure 1
        stylish-haskell-0.5.8.0 depends on conduit-1.0.8 which failed to install.
        yaml-0.8.5.1 depends on conduit-1.0.8 which failed to install.
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert here, but I think this is caused by Mavericks replacing the standard `gcc` with a version of `clang` wrapped with a `gcc`-semi-compatible wrapper. It make GHC choke from time to time. You can fix it by editing `/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.3/settings` so that the `"C compiler command"` entry points to a valid `gcc`.

For instance, I installed `gcc` 4.8 from Homebrew and then changed the settings line to

```
 ("C compiler command", "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9")
```

Comment: I haven't "upgraded" to Mavericks, so that's probably not it.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Also, I don't appear to have a /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.3 directory.  Should that be concering?

Comment: I'm not sure. I grabbed that directory by looking at the global path that shows up when I type `ghc-pkg list`.

Comment: Did you install the haskell platform with homebrew?

Comment: No---My fresh install procedure is: (1) GHC, (2) HP via `cabal-install  array==0.4.0.1 ...` (you get the full list from [here](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/blob/master/haskell-platform.cabal)) (3) sandboxes from there on out.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, I don't want gcc in the path before llvm. What I do is edit source file again and again, and wait for next release of haskell-platform.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! I haven't "upgraded" to Mavericks either. However, way too many Cabal packages were blowing out on me on similar looking errors, and the Haskell ecosystem just isn't that bad, something had to be up. One should remember that threads like this are never just about the OP's problem, the OP just puts the ball in play. Here, this answer knew of some circumstances where their fix helped, but never proclaimed themselves an expert on exactly where it would help. Lacking any other clues how to proceed, I tried this and it worked!

Comment: @kocho: If using the Haskell Platform, the path is /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ghc-7.6.3

Comment: I've seen a bunch of problems with haskell platform binary installer + clang, even when updating ghc settings or using the clang-wrapper script (which does the same thing). The sure way to fix all these problems seems to be to install haskell-platform from homebrew.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in some of the other answers this is due to gcc being replaced by Clang starting with at least Xcode 5.

GHC leans on GCC's preprocessor in order to support c++ like `#something` macros and it looks like Clang behaves slightly differently which causes compilation of haskell sources containing such macros to fail.

The fix is actually displayed prominently on the Haskell Platform's Mac page:
https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

It consists of a simple bash script which acts as a wrapper around Clang.

To install it:

- Go to https://www.haskell.org/platform/ghc-clang-wrapper.
- Press command-s to save the script in your download folder.
- Install it by running the following instructions in a terminal:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  chmod +x ghc-clang-wrapper
  ./ghc-clang-wrapper
  ```
- Then follow the simple instructions it prints.

Once that's done, simply relaunch the cabal install command and it will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can fix work by following workaround.

https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/issues/147

Comment: Mavericks Users: The following instructions from a comment in the Github Issue: http://justtesting.org/post/64947952690/the-glasgow-haskell-compiler-ghc-on-os-x-10-9