# cabal install text-1.1.1.3 fails

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to install a library with no dependencies with cabal and it's failing. I'm new to Haskell (and Cabal, for that matter), so I'm not certain if there's something I need to do or if the library I'm trying to install has some issues that need addressing.

Below is the full output of the "cabal install" command. I'm running cabal 1.20.0.3, ghc 7.6.3, and Mac OS X 10.9.4.

```
$ cabal install text-1.1.1.3
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring text-1.1.1.3...
Building text-1.1.1.3...
Preprocessing library text-1.1.1.3...

Data/Text.hs:9:52:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Copyright   : (c) 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 Bryan O'Sullivan,
                                                   ^

Data/Text.hs:90:12:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        , foldl'
               ^

Data/Text.hs:92:13:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        , foldl1'
                ^

Data/Text.hs:153:14:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        --, lines'
                 ^

Data/Text.hs:274:15:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- character \"&#xfffd;\" (U+FFFD).  Functions that perform this
              ^

Data/Text.hs:276:5:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- \"Performs replacement on invalid scalar values\".
    ^

Data/Text.hs:309:12:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- phrase \"Subject to fusion\".
           ^

Data/Text.hs:456:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^

Data/Text.hs:493:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:509:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^

Data/Text.hs:526:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^

Data/Text.hs:543:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^

Data/Text.hs:570:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:575:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:580:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:585:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:590:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:595:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:600:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:632:42:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- In (unlikely) bad cases, this function's time complexity degrades
                                         ^

Data/Text.hs:689:33:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- the Armenian small ligature \"&#xfb13;\" (men now, U+FB13) is case
                                ^

Data/Text.hs:690:28:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- folded to the sequence \"&#x574;\" (men, U+0574) followed by
                           ^

Data/Text.hs:691:5:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- \"&#x576;\" (now, U+0576), while the Greek \"&#xb5;\" (micro sign,
    ^

Data/Text.hs:692:31:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- U+00B5) is case folded to \"&#x3bc;\" (small letter mu, U+03BC)
                              ^

Data/Text.hs:702:15:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- instance, \"&#x130;\" (Latin capital letter I with dot above,
              ^

Data/Text.hs:703:34:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- U+0130) maps to the sequence \"i\" (Latin small letter i, U+0069)
                                 ^

Data/Text.hs:704:17:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- followed by \" &#x307;\" (combining dot above, U+0307).
                ^

Data/Text.hs:713:26:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- instance, the German \"&#xdf;\" (eszett, U+00DF) maps to the
                         ^

Data/Text.hs:714:25:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- two-letter sequence \"SS\".
                        ^

Data/Text.hs:734:46:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- guides disagree on whether the book name \"The Hill of the Red
                                             ^

Data/Text.hs:735:8:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Fox\" is correctly title cased&#x2014;but this function will
       ^

Data/Text.hs:761:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:814:6:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
foldl' :: (a -> Char -> a) -> a -> Text -> a
     ^

Data/Text.hs:816:17:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
{-# INLINE foldl' #-}
                ^

Data/Text.hs:825:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
foldl1' :: (Char -> Char -> Char) -> Text -> Char
      ^

Data/Text.hs:827:18:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
{-# INLINE foldl1' #-}
                 ^

Data/Text.hs:849:20:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
concat ts = case ts' of
                   ^

Data/Text.hs:854:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        ts' = L.filter (not . null) ts
          ^

Data/Text.hs:855:48:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        len = sumP "concat" $ L.map lengthWord16 ts'
                                                   ^

Data/Text.hs:860:22:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
          foldM step 0 ts' >> return arr
                         ^

Data/Text.hs:936:52:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- | /O(n)/ Like a combination of 'map' and 'foldl''. Applies a
                                                   ^

Data/Text.hs:981:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:1035:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:1074:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:1104:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:1121:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:1142:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^

Data/Text.hs:1255:42:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- In (unlikely) bad cases, this function's time complexity degrades
                                         ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
29 warnings and 20 errors generated.
Failed to install text-1.1.1.3
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
text-1.1.1.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: What OS ? [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851315/error-installing-stylish-haskell-on-mac-os-x-on-haskell-platform-2013-2-0-0).

Comment: OS X 10.9.4 (going to update the question as well).

Comment: @Sibi the answer you linked to was exactly what I needed. Thanks!